# PDO insert null instead of empty with dynamic statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PDO with a dynamically created statement, I am running into errors when I try to insert empty data into decimal fields, I believe the issue is I need input `null` instead of empty. Here is my code:

```
    try {
    $options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    function escape_mysql_identifier($field){
        return "`".str_replace("`", "``", $field)."`";
    }

    function prepared_insert($pdo, $table, $data) {
        $keys = array_keys($data);
        $keys = array_map('escape_mysql_identifier', $keys);
        $fields = implode(",", $keys);
        $table = escape_mysql_identifier($table);
        $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($keys) - 1) . '?';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
        $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array_values($data));
    }

    prepared_insert($conn, 'products', $data);

    $id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    if ($id > 0) {
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success'));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array ('response'=>'error','errorMessage'=>'Row not created'));
    }

}catch(PDOException $e){
    
    echo json_encode(array ('response'=>'error','errorMessage'=>$e->getMessage()));
}
    $conn = null;
```

How can I make this insert `null` instead of empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218750/discussion-between-tony-and-your-common-sense).

Comment: In order to let people help you with the error, you are supposed to provide the **error message** you get. It is impossible to fix the unknown error.

Comment: $data = array_filter($data); will remove elements with empty values.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Bingo, that's it! If you want to leave that as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Change your table settings. Set it to accept null in that column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `column` `column` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: _Small Point_ ___I try to insert empty data into DECIMAL field___

Comment: If empty just insert nothing. By default it will set it null

Comment: Yeah dude, I am pretty sure I already have this set and it is giving me an error if I try to insert empty